# How to replace a current word on a string using python 2.7?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

Here is my strings:

```
marker = "AFK"
replacement = "away from keyboard"
line = "I will now go to sleep and be AFK until lunch time tomorrow."
```

I want to replace "AFK" on "away from keyboard" in my `line` variable.

What the easiest way to do that on python 2.7?

Thanks.

Comment: `line = line.replace(marker, replacement)`

Comment: this is an answer actually :)

Comment: Might wish to consider word boundaries in there.... eg: does "notAFKatthemoment" count for a suitable replacement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You replace with `replace` like this (you also have to replace `line` with the altered string returned by `replace` since strings are immutable):

```
line = line.replace(marker, replacement)
```